# Commiting and flushing translog in ElasticSearch - misunderstanding

Tags: elasticsearch

On many blogs and in reference I have read about flushing translog, there is plenty of information which cause headache and some misunderstandings:

1. Is translog kept for replicated shards? Why?
2. If `GET /_cat/allocation` includes translogs?
3. What is difference between flush after exceeding disk space threshold (default 512 MB) and between flush after one second (flush, filesystem cache, segments). Can anyone tell the difference?
4. `index.translog.retention.age`

What does it mean? Does it mean that translogs within 12GB takes arbitrarily much disk space?

Answer (score 0):

flushing. from guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-flush.html

Examples

Flush a specific index

```
`POST /kimchy/_flush`
```

curl

```
`curl -X POST "localhost:9200/kimchy/_flush?pretty"`
```

Flush several indices

```
`POST /kimchy,elasticsearch/_flush`
```

curl

```
 `curl -X POST "localhost:9200/kimchy,elasticsearch/_flush?pretty"`
```

Flush all indices

```
'POST /_flush'
```

curl

```
'curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_flush?pretty"'
```